# Configurable Product for all the associated products

Tags: configurable-product, custom-options

Is it possible to create a configurable product, which works both ways?

So for example:

Product A is configurable, which means that you can choose a particular option let say color or size, and when you do so, it becomes Product B.

When I look up product B individually, then I want to get the same options, in order to get Product A en so on...

I want the associated products that has been created from product A, to have the same option for color and size.

I hope someone can help me out with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

With Magento 2.4, you can create a Configurable Product with multiple associated Simple Products based on different attributes, such as color or size. However, the functionality you're describing, where the associated Simple Products have the same options to become other Simple Products, is not available by default in Magento.

To achieve this functionality, you can try the following:

1. Custom extension: Develop a custom Magento extension to override the
   default behavior and add the desired functionality. This will
   require programming knowledge, especially in PHP and Magento
   development. You can create a custom module that listens to an event
   like controller_action_predispatch_catalog_product_view, checks if
   the current product is a Simple Product associated with a
   Configurable Product, and then loads the parent Configurable Product
   with all available options.
2. Third-party extensions: Look for third-party extensions that might
   offer similar functionality. Some extensions may allow you to
   customize product options and display them on Simple Products as
   well. Keep in mind that these extensions may not work exactly as you
   described, and you might need to customize them or request support
   from the extension developers.
3. Grouped products: Consider using Grouped Products instead of
   Configurable Products. Grouped Products can display a list of
   associated Simple Products together on one page, and customers can
   select quantities for each Simple Product. While this doesn't offer
   the exact functionality you're looking for, it can be a more
   straightforward way to display multiple product options together.

Please note that custom development and third-party extensions might affect your store's performance and compatibility with future updates. Always make sure to test your changes in a development environment before deploying them to your live store.